# python regex match and replace dates

Tags: python, regex, datetime, date

I need to match dates in form:

January 10, 2012

And replace in form:

10 January 2012

Here is what I have so far:

```
        pattern = re.findall(r'(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s\d\d,\s\d{4}', text)
        print pattern
```

How do i replace?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post your code and any specific problems you're having.

Comment: @Doug T. - Even if it's not, it's still not a passable question. As it stands, the question appears to be "I don't know regular expressions, write one for me."

Comment: Yes I need help convert from form January 10, 2012 to form 10 January 2012

Comment: @michael: "replace" is entirely the wrong concept.  You're just formatting the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) to parse the date and [`strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) to generate the new string. There is no reason to use a regex in this case.

```
In [1]: import time
In [2]: tm = time.strptime('January 10, 2012', '%B %d, %Y')
In [3]: time.strftime('%d %B %Y', tm)
Out[4]: '10 January 2012'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in general, something like this:

find: `^(January) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4})$`
replace `$2 $1 $3`